# LibGDX - prevent scrolled event in Ui Actor(Window) not work, but other events works

Tags: java, android, events, libgdx

As in title, when you want to prevent some events from being propagate you are free to go, except one event "scrolled". It just not works. Can someone tell me why?

```
Window abc = new Window("Tools", skin);
abc.setY(5);
abc.setResizable(false);
abc.setMovable(false);
abc.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 300, 0);
abc.setSize(300, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
addActor(abc);

abc.addCaptureListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true; //it will stop event from being propagate
    }

    public boolean scrolled(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int a) {
        return true; //it wont stop event from being propagate (because method isn't even called!
    }
});

abc.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true; //it will stop event from being propagate
    }

    public boolean scrolled(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int a) {
        return true; //it wont stop event from being propagate (because method isn't even called!
    }
});
```

Besides of it, what is the difference between addCaptureListener and addListener?

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX UI is terrible coded.. Who did this? Code below is workaround for scrolling bug. It's ugly, because breaks the libgdx-ui rules, but these rules are ugly too..

EDIT (new solution)

```
abc.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public void enter (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        setScrollFocus(abc);
    }

    public void exit (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        setScrollFocus(null);
    }

    public boolean scrolled(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int a) {
        return true; //now it works
    }
});
```

(old solution)

```
public class FixedStage extends Stage {
    Vector2 tempCoords = new Vector2();

    public FixedStage(Viewport viewport) {
        super(viewport);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
        screenToStageCoordinates(tempCoords.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()));

        Actor target = hit(tempCoords.x, tempCoords.y, true);
        if (target == null) target = getRoot();

        InputEvent event = Pools.obtain(InputEvent.class);
        event.setStage(this);
        event.setType(InputEvent.Type.scrolled);
        event.setScrollAmount(amount);
        event.setStageX(tempCoords.x);
        event.setStageY(tempCoords.y);
        target.fire(event);
        boolean handled = event.isHandled();
        Pools.free(event);
        return handled;
    }
}
```